# Find the average number of activities in the last 7 days

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have data contained in a database, through a query I can read values ​​(key) [Date, Activity Number, other value]

I should be able to find a way to get the average number of activities in the last 7 days (obviously the last 7 days are to be compared with today's date).

```
findStatistics() {
    return ......
      .remoteDB
      .query(
        'statistics2/statistics',
        {
          group: true,
        }
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response ", response)
```

gives me these values:

```
response  {
    "rows": [
        {
            "key": [
                "2019-10-28",
                "02",
                "20191028103516"
            ],
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "key": [
                "2019-10-31",
                "05",
                "20191031122358"
            ],
            "value": 2
        },
        {
            "key": [
                "2019-11-05",
                "01",
                "20191105172615"
            ],
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "key": [
                "2019-11-05",
                "01",
                "20191105173005"
            ],
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "key": [
                "2019-11-05",
                "01",
                "2019115151417"
            ],
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "key": [
                "2019-11-05",
                "03",
                "20191105170543"
            ],
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "key": [
                "2019-11-05",
                "05",
                "20191031122358"
            ],
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

as you can see in the "key", the first value is the Date, the second is the number of activity.

What I have to get is an average corresponding to the number of activities per day.

How can I do?? thank you.

Comment: Which solutions have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
const days = response.rows.reduce((acc, r) => {
  const date = r.key[0]
  if (!acc[date]) {
    acc[date] = 1
  } else {
    acc[date] += 1
  }
  return acc
}, {})

const values = Object.values(days)

const avg = values.reduce((acc, d) => acc + d) / values.length

console.log(avg)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) this is the average and it works :) What I search to obtain is the average in the last 7 days :(

Comment: Get keys from days, sort and get last 7.

Comment: my problem is how to recover the last 7 days (not last 7 elements)